# Google Analytics 4 Setup Using "Connected Site Tags"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Am I understanding it correctly that to get started with Google Analytics 4 (GA4) that I set-up the property in GA first and then go to my Universal property > Tracking Info > Tracking Code > Connected Site Tags and then enter the GA4 code and the new information will be entered into the Universal property without duplication (meaning, I won't be seeing Universal and GA4, just the new data)?

Would it be best to keep these two separate for now and monitor the data in each property by adding the GA4 code below the Universal code? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The two systems are different and use a different data model so you can't have the data mixed, the two properties are distinct.

Best practices say to track data in parallel to both old and new property.